# i hava a code to make a call in background but it id force stopping everytime i used onclick to call this method in my xml file this is my code

Tags: android

```
package com.example.admin.emergency;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class second extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    }

public void call (View v){


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + 
"123456789"));


    startService (callIntent);

}

}
```

Comment: i added the premission to

Comment: put logcat, without it we can not tell you solution

Comment: logcat says that service intent must be explicit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a call from your app. Instead of startService you should call startActivity. So for example like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+PHONE_NUMBER_GOES_HERE);   
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

You also need the permission added to AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are two intents to call/start calling: **ACTION_CALL** and **ACTION_DIAL**.

ACTION_DIAL will only open the dialer with the number filled in, but allows the user to actually call or reject the call.

> ACTION_CALL will immediately call the number and requires an extra
>   permission.

So make sure you have the permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

> 

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 String phNum = "tel:" + "1234567890";
 myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
 startActivity( myIntent )
```

http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android/